# Why I am getting these issues with Sitecore Helix Visual Studio Templates (Anders Laub) on Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: helix, visual-studio

I've installed the [Sitecore Helix Visual Studio Templates from Anders Laub (laub plus co)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndersLaublaubplusco.SitecoreHelixVisualStudioTemplates) and created an empty Helix project running Visual Studio 2017 in Administrator mode.

Once I add a new Project, I noticed that:

1 - Visual Studio complains about missing Unicorn config files as if they were deleted

2 - When I build the solution I get error for missing Sitecore assemblies

[image]

The Helix Templates were also installed running Visual Studio 2017 as administrator.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting these errors because the default templates that are installed contain some errors.

### Sitecore References Fix:

In your folder where you installed the templates, find all the files called `$modulenamespace$.csproj`. In those files you will find these lines:

```
<Reference Include="Sitecore.Kernel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences.8.2.161115\lib\NET452\Sitecore.Kernel.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Sitecore.Mvc, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\Sitecore.Mvc.NoReferences.8.2.161115\lib\NET452\Sitecore.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

Notice that the package version is hard coded here. This should be changed to `$sitecoreVersion$` like this:

```
<Reference Include="Sitecore.Kernel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences.$sitecoreVersion$\lib\NET452\Sitecore.Kernel.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Sitecore.Mvc, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\Sitecore.Mvc.NoReferences.$sitecoreVersion$\lib\NET452\Sitecore.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

### Config Files Fix:

In the project module templates, it is referencing the config files correctly in the `.csproj` file, but on disk they are in the wrong place - see this image:

[image: Wrong Folder Name]

If you just rename that `Feature` folder to `Project` it will work and pick up your config files correctly.

I have a PR waiting to get merged for it https://github.com/LaubPlusCo/LaubPlusCo.Helix.VsTemplates/pull/2

Comment: Thanks, mate. It just fixed my issue. Have you noticed any issue having this extension enabled? Once I have it enabled, sometimes VS IDE breaks randomly and it restarts. It happens when I open a new solution for example or when I copy and paste something while with the "add new Helix project dialog" opened.

Comment: I haven't noticed any issues with it yet. I have been using it on a couple of projects. Definitely makes life easier :)

Comment: One minute ago, Visual Studio 2017 just crashed and had to be restarted. =/

Comment: Check your Application log in the event viewer. That might give you an idea as to what is causing it.